# Is $f(x, y) := {1 \over x^2 + y^2}$ function with a norm?

Tags: functions, normed-spaces

Let

$f: \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$,

$$f(x, y) := {1 \over x^2 + y^2}$$ for $(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$, $0$ otherwise.

In of my books, it is claimed that this would be a function of the type

$$\Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R,$$

$$x \rightarrow f(||x||),$$

but why is that the case? $||x||$ denotes a norm, right? But what kind of norm does $x^2 + y^2$ denote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may take the [euclidian norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Examples)
$$
||x||=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}=(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}.
$$ Then can you identify $f$?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Wouldn't we have $f(||x||) =$ $1 \over \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$?

Comment: Well, then $f(x, y) = {1 \over (x + y)^2}$?

Comment: You have $f(x_1,x_2)=\dfrac1{||(x_1,x_2)||^2}=\dfrac1{||x||^2}$.